# Uninstalling/reverting Thunderbird updates

Tags: updates, thunderbird

Is there an easy way to uninstall an update to Thunderbird in Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for different versions of Thunderbird available, using `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache policy thunderbird
thunderbird:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:24.1.1+build1-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
  Version table:
     1:24.1.1+build1-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main amd64 Packages
     17.0.5+build1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
```

If you want to install the older version you can use `apt-get install package=version`:

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird=17.0.5+build1-0ubuntu1
```